Jboss undertow is rejecting the host due to which url is unaccessible
I'm trying to access jboss console using ldap authentication. Although the authentication is successful, undertow is rejecting the request which inturn throws 403 error
2024-07-29 07:26:00,350 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.domain.http.api.undertow] (management I/O-1) Request rejected due to HOST/ORIGIN mis-match.
2024-07-29 07:26:00,350 DEBUG [io.undertow.predicate] (management I/O-1) Response code set to [403] for HttpServerExchange{ GET/console/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.8bd2b33b.ttf}.
2024-07-29 07:26:00,350 DEBUG [io.undertow.request] (management I/O-1) Matched prefix path /console for path /console/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.8bd2b33b.ttf
2024-07-29 07:26:00,350 DEBUG [io.undertow.request] (management I/O-1) Matched default handler path /OpenSans-Regular-webfont.8bd2b33b.ttf
2024-07-29 07:26:00,350 DEBUG [io.undertow.request] (management I/O-1) Matched default handler path /OpenSans-Regular-webfont.8bd2b33b.ttf
2024-07-29 07:26:00,909 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.domain.http.api.undertow] (management I/O-2) Request rejected due to HOST/ORIGIN mis-match.
2024-07-29 07:26:00,909 DEBUG [io.undertow.predicate] (management I/O-2) Response code set to [403] for HttpServerExchange{ GET /console/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.1f77ed1d.woff}.
Please help on this.
